# PHP HTML cart, using HTML template

Tags: php, html, templates, field

I'm trying to modify the following code to show all custom fields. This code shows only the custom fields that have a price, but I want to show **all** the custom fields including the free ones.

```
<td valign="top">{$contents[0].category_name} - <strong>{$contents[0].name}</strong> {if $contents[2][0]}({$contents[2][0].name}){/if}<br/>
          </td>
          <td align="center">{if $contents[0].setup!=0}{$contents[0].setup|price:$currency}{else}-{/if}</td>
          <td align="center">{if $contents[0].price==0}<strong>{$lang.Free}</strong>{elseif $contents[0].prorata_amount}
         <strong> {$contents[0].prorata_amount|price:$currency}</strong>
           ({$lang.prorata} {$contents[0].prorata_date|dateformat:$date_format}){else}<strong>{$contents[0].price|price:$currency}</strong>{/if}</td>
        </tr>
         {/if}

        {if $cart_contents[1]}
                {foreach from=$cart_contents[1] item=cstom}
                {if $cstom.total>0}
                <tr >
          <td valign="top" class="blighter fs11" style="padding-left:15px">{$cstom.fullname}<br/>
          </td>
          <td align="center" class="blighter fs11">{if $cstom.setup!=0}{$cstom.setup|price:$currency}{else}-{/if}</td>
          <td align="center" class="blighter fs11"><strong>{if $cstom.price==0}{$lang.Free}{elseif $cstom.prorata_amount}{$cstom.prorata_amount|price:$currency}{else}{$cstom.price|price:$currency}{/if}</strong></td>
        </tr>


                {/if}
                {/foreach}

            {/if}   

      {if $contents[3]}

      {foreach from=$contents[3] item=addon}
      <tr >
        <td>{$lang.addon} <strong>{$addon.name}</strong></td>
        <td  align="center">{if $addon.setup!=0}{$addon.setup|price:$currency}{else}-{/if}</td>
        <td align="center">{if $addon.price==0}<strong>{$lang.Free}</strong>{elseif $addon.prorata_amount}<strong>{$addon.prorata_amount|price:$currency}</strong> ({$lang.prorata} {$addon.prorata_date|dateformat:$date_format}){else}<strong>{$addon.price|price:$currency}</strong>{/if}</td>
```

I guess I should modify this area at line 39

```
{if $cart_contents[1]}
        {foreach from=$cart_contents[1] item=cstom}
        {if $cstom.total>0}
```

But I don't know how to do it. I hope someone help me regarding this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: And "dunno" isn't really a word.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just removing the if

```
    {if $cart_contents[1]}
        {foreach from=$cart_contents[1] item=cstom}
        <tr >
  <td valign="top" class="blighter fs11" style="padding-left:15px">{$cstom.fullname}<br/>
  </td>
  <td align="center" class="blighter fs11">{if $cstom.setup!=0}{$cstom.setup|price:$currency}{else}-{/if}</td>
  <td align="center" class="blighter fs11"><strong>{if $cstom.price==0}{$lang.Free}{elseif $cstom.prorata_amount}{$cstom.prorata_amount|price:$currency}{else}{$cstom.price|price:$currency}{/if}</strong></td>
</tr>
        {/foreach}

    {/if}
```

Comment: hello McWafflestix , i edit my post and made it around the code only , hope it's ok now .... cambraca the dunno word mean i don't know .... thanks Sven Almgren for your respond but i try it before and the page not loading when i removed the whole code